# Changing one element attribute value in List of objects also change all the elements value

Tags: c#, list, oop

this is my class named "Objek".

```
public class Objek
{
    public int id;
    public int tipe;
    public int bentuk;
    public List<int> x { get; set; }
    public List<int> y { get; set; }
    public int xC { get; set; }
    public int yC { get; set; }
    public Color Warna { get; set; }
    public Objek()
    {
        this.Warna = Color.Black;
        this.x = new List<int>();
        this.y = new List<int>();
    }
    public Objek(int tipe, int bentuk)
    {
        this.tipe = tipe;
        this.bentuk = bentuk;

        this.Warna = Color.Black;
        this.x = new List<int>();
        this.y = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

then in the form1.cs I declared this globally (outside any method):

```
Objek temp = new Objek();
```

after I input the value of the "temp", I stored it to a List:

`List<Objek> Objek = new List<Objek>();` with `Objek.Add(temp);`
the problem is whenever I changed one of the element's attribute value (ex: `Objek[0].Warna = Color.Red`) after stored more than 1 "temp" object, all `Objek[0, 1, ..., n].Warna` also changed to Red.

Can someone explain me where is my fault in these code?

Comment: You are storing multiple references to the same instance of `Objek` in your list, not creating multiple instances of `Objeck` and storing each of them in your list.

Comment: Can you add relevant code from `form1.cs` here ?  Especially the part when you add values, as it is by now we can only speculate of the cause of your problem. It looks very likely that you add the same object and not a different one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are adding the same object reference to the List. Move `Objek temp = new Objek();` inside the method so that you are creating a new object everytime, otherwise everytime you call this method it is using/adding **the same object**.

[image]

Comment: but in my code, i am using more than one method. The object "temp" that we are talking about were used with more than one method. Can you give me any solution for that? thanks

Comment: Then, every time you need to create a new object to modify you will need to replace your temp object by writing: temp = new Objek();

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are storing multiple references to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the same object more than once so you only have 1 object that is inserted into the list several times therefore changing one changes all. You should be copying the object or creating multiple. This can be done using ICloneable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx, a library like AutoMapper http://automapper.org/ or just create a new object.